# Can I mmap to file in JVM?

Tags: jvm, mmap

I want to mmap to file, i.e., without MAP_ANON flag.
So I modified mmap calls in os_linux.cpp, and then JVM failed with SIGSEGV.
How can I mmap to a particular file or block device??

Comment: Please provide more details. Is `java.nio.FileChannel.map()` not what are looking for?

Comment: No. I mean mmap function in JVM HotSpot runtime. 

Java heap allocation is using mmap() internally.

In hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp, a function named commit_memory_impl() does the task of allocation from OS.

I want this mmap to map to a file or block device.